# PushViewController and Popview Controller on uinavigation bar from initial view controller

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to iphone. I have a small confusion on uinavigation controllers that is I want a navigation bar in initial view controller in that view controller there is a button in navigation bar when we click on that it will push the another view controller(second view controller) from that there is a back button if we click on that i want to pop that view controller and come back to initial view controller.If any body know this please help me .If you explain with some code it will better to understand us.

The following code i have written so,far here present modal view controller and dismiss model view controller is working but pushview controller and popview controller is not working

In appDelegate i have written like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        //create a window
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        //biblePlayerController is an instance of BiblePlayerViewController class and then set the biblePlayerController as a rootViewController to the window
        self.biblePlayerController = [[BiblePlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BiblePlayerViewController" bundle:nil];

       navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.biblePlayerController];

      // self.window.rootViewController = self.biblePlayerController;
        [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];  
//make the window visible
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        return YES;   

}   

//In initial View controller there is a navigation on that there is a download button code for that is 

//BiblePlayerViewController.m
 UIBarButtonItem *downloadButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(gotoProgressViewController:)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = downloadButton;

- (IBAction)gotoProgressViewController:(id)sender {
    @try {

        //ShowProgressViewCont is initialized with the nibName
        showProgressViewController = [[ShowProgressViewCont alloc]initWithNibName:@"ShowProgressViewCont" bundle:nil];

        //UINavigationController is initialized with the rootViewController showProgressViewController
        navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:showProgressViewController]; 

        //The transition style of the navigationController is set to UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve
        navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

        //Presents a modal view managed by the given view controller to the user.Here navigation Controller that manages the modal view.
        [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
      //  [navigationController pushViewController:showProgressViewController animated:YES];
    }
    @catch(NSException * e){NSLog(@"Exception At10: %s %d %s %s %@",__FILE__,__LINE__,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FUNCTION__,e);}@finally{}
}
```

In the above code presentModalViewController is working but pushViewController is not working why. If any body know this please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are in ParentViewController and by pressing Child Btn you want to go to ChildViewController.

```
- (void) childBtnPressed : (id) sender
{
     ChildViewController *makeNewObject = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChildViewController" bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:makeNewObject animated:YES];
     [makeNewObject release];
}
```

Now in your ChildViewController.m file, write this on the Back Btn action to go back to the Parent View Controller.

```
- (void) backBtnPressed : (id) sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On clicking the button in the Navigationbar, Push nextview

```
- (IBAction)NextViewAction:(id) sender
{
     NextViewController *NxtView = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:NxtView animated:YES];
     [NxtView release];
}
```

To Pop from NextViewController

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```